# Jquery Foreach After Clicking Button

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach

My site generates html code with php and I need to toggle a section to show after clicking a button. Problem is with this code, after clicking, only reveals one item.

```
$("body").on('click','.btn',(function(){
document.querySelector(".hide").style.display = "block";

});
```

I need it to iterate over each .hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep using jQuery, specifically the [`.show()` method](https://api.jquery.com/show/)

> Display the matched **elements**

```js
$(document.body).on("click", ".btn", () => {
  $(".hide").show()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this makes more sense. Just remove the hide class?

```
$("body").on('click', '.btn', (function() {
      $(".hide").removeClass('hide');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".hide").forEach( hide => {
  hide.style.display = "block";
})
```

Comment: Hi Emre, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you explain a bit what your code does to solve the problem in the question?

Comment: s/he wanted to iterate over each `hide` class elements and the code does that?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and obvious to a more experienced developer. However, StackOverflow automatically sends short "just code" answers into a review queue where it might get deleted by an overzealous reviewer. I've got yours in the queue and chose to add a short comment instead of a deletion vote as you are a new contributor :)